# How to use ruby output in html?

Tags: html, ruby

I have a ruby program to get the json from api and seperate the values from it and display it.
What i need to do is present the output in a html form. How can i take the values from the ruby and pass it to html so that i can use that value.

Comment: Do you have some sample code showing what you are doing? It's much easier for us to suggest changes or fixes if we have SOME sort of idea what you have done. Without it we are shooting in the dark. For instance, how do you "seperate the values from it"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a great tutorial about this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) gem

For example, the template `foo.html.haml`:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Rotten Potatoes!

  %body
    %h1.title Rotten Potatoes!

      Hey = yield!
```

Then pass the name to templete:

```
template = Tilt::ERBTemplate.new('foo.html.haml')
output = template.render { 'Joe' } # => html code with phrase 'Hey Joe!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just add another line of code to redirect to another page with parameters. Hence you can receive the parameters and render it to html.